# Rails bootstrap: 2 columns in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm trying to represent a nested form on 2 columns. I'm using simple_form and nested_form. The problem is when I put a  to close the first column the link_to_add doesn't work. This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <%= simple_nested_form_for @object1, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input_field :name %>
      </div> <!-- This div is to close the first column -->
      <div class="span8">
      <%= f.link_to_add "Add a object2", :object2, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :object2,:html => { :class => 'span8 form-inline' } do |s| %>
        <%= s.input_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I open to any change of the plugins to use. I just need to represent a nested form with more than two nested objects.

Comment: @rb512 sorry, I don't see where is the problem. one :object2 is on the link_to_add that is the nested resource I wanted to add and the other one is the simple_fields_for that prints the currents object2 on object1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a lot of closing divs. I'm not sure about this code, but try this:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @object1, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <%= f.input :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <%= f.link_to_add "Add a object2", :object2, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :object2, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |s| %>
        <%= s.input :name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I can also recommend similar to nested_forms: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. It is more maintained.